# Hibernate. Как подключить mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql:jdbc://localhost:3306/count_words?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow</property>
            <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="connection.password">mysql</property>
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>

            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="format_sql">true</property>
            <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>

            <mapping class="ru.callinsicght.countwords.model.AllModels"/>
            <mapping class="ru.callinsicght.countwords.model.Roles"/>
            <mapping class="ru.callinsicght.countwords.model.User"/>
            <mapping 
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

#### pom.xml

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"




    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>count_words</groupId>
        <artifactId>count_words</artifactId>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        </properties>
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>count_words_local</id>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                </activation>
                <properties>
                    <db.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/count_words?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow</db.url>
                    <db.username>root</db.username>
                    <db.password>mysql</db.password>
                    <db.driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</db.driver>
                </properties>
            </profile>
            <profile>
                <id>count_words</id>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                </activation>
                <properties>
                    <db.url>jdbc:mysql://10.201.2.2:3306/count_words?serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow</db.url>
                    <db.username>nesh</db.username>
                    <db.password>12345</db.password>
                    <db.driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</db.driver>
                </properties>
            </profile>

        </profiles>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>validate</id>
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                                <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                                <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>${basedir}/db/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <url>${db.url}</url>
                        <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
                        <username>${db.username}</username>
                        <password>${db.password}</password>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>update</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>8</source>
                        <target>8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <!--        <dependency>-->
    <!--            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
    <!--            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
    <!--            <version>3.1</version>-->
    <!--        </dependency>-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.13-beta-2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>42.2.5.jre7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Hibernate START-->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
                <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.15</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Hibernate END-->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Strat Spring -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.8</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Если в файле hibernate прописываю настройки postresql то все работает как правильно прописать mysql и правельные ли у меня зависимости?

Comment: Не могли бы вы добавить в ваш вопрос ошибку при компиляции

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, у вас при попытке подключения MySQL вылезает ошибка "“Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'”, так? В таком случае, как мне тут в марте подсказали, надо указывать параметры

- serverTimezone
- useSSL

а код в src/main/resources/application.properties

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
```

должен выглядеть как

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example?serverTimezone=Asia/Tashkent&useSSL=false
```